# Should assumptions be used for SIMPLE linear regression analysis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Should I use the same assumptions checking during the linear regression analysis as I use them for Multiple regression analysis? Can it be used at all?

in assumptions, I mean: 1.  multicollinearity; 2. normality; 3. influential cases; 4. homoscedasticity; and 5. autocorrelation.

Comment: Don't forget the linearity assumption.

Comment: Are you sure about the title? Of course, you need some assumptions; linear regression is not completely free of assumptions. But that is perhaps not the real question here, or is it?

Comment: I meant the difference between assumptions for linear regression and multiple linear regression.

Comment: The assumptions are the same. But note that if you're not doing inference (the usual normal theory tests, confidence intervals, prediction intervals etc) then you don't need to be making the assumptions. .... Given that both multiple and simple regression are linear, is it necessary to capitalize the word LINEAR in your title and body-text?

Comment: Based on you answer it really seems that you should change your title. Also, when replying to a comment, please use "@RichardHardy", otherwise I do not get notified of your comments.

Comment: Even if not doing inference, failure to satisfy certain assumptions can hurt.  For example in a very asymmetric residual distribution one might not even be best served by estimating means (which is what regression does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "assumption" that goes away when you simplify a model from multiple regression down to linear regression is multicollinearity.  That's for a simple reason.  When you have one single independent variable, it does not have any other variables to be collinear with.  So, the issue evaporates.  Most all other assumptions entail testing the residual of your regression.  And, for the testing of residuals it makes no difference whether your regression has one independent variable (linear regression) or more than one independent variable(multiple regression).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it may not be related here, but could I ask you one more question please: In multiply regression, how to calculate percentage of variance of specific variable using r squared and standardized beta?

Comment: for the upper post..

Comment: Co-linearity is not an assumption.  It is a challenge although often it doesn't harm us.

Comment: @Frankharell it is indeed an assumption on the relationship in the population, you have a sample so naturally it is something to think about

Comment: Geo, your earlier questions within your comments entails mainly calculating standardized regression coefficients.  It is very easy.  Let's say we calculate it for X1.  Its standardized coefficient of X1 = X1 reg. coefficient times X1 Standard deviation/Y Standard deviation.  Let's say X1 has a reg. coif. of 0.5 and a standard deviation of 3.  Meanwhile, Y has a standard deviation of 1.  X1 standardized coefficient: 0.5 times 3/1 = 1.5.